# Promise returns undefined - Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-promise

Hi I am trying to get the result from **sign_vals** and use it in **sign_request** , my problem is that I keep getting undefined when I wanna use the value in sign_vals this is potentially a small issue but I hope someone can assist. Thanks

````
    const vals = username + "|" + ikey;

    const duo_sig = await this._sign_vals(
      skey,
      vals,
      this.DUO_PREFIX,
      this.DUO_EXPIRE
    );

    const app_sig = await this._sign_vals(
      akey,
      vals,
      this.APP_PREFIX,
      this.APP_EXPIRE
    );

    console.log(app_sig);
    const sig_request = duo_sig + ":" + app_sig;
    return sig_request;
  }

  _sign_vals(key, vals, prefix, expire: number) {
    var exp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + expire;

    var val = vals + "|" + exp;
    var sig;
    var b64 = Buffer.from(val).toString("base64");
    const cookie = prefix + "|" + b64;

    this.computehmac(key, cookie).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      const hexedstring = Buffer.from(data).toString("hex");

      const output = cookie + "|" + hexedstring;
      this.output = output;
      return this.output;
    });

    //this.output = (await this.cookie) + "|" + this.sig;
  }

  computehmac(key: any, cookie: any) {
    const computation = hmac.compute(key, cookie, "SHA-1");
    return computation;
  }```
````

Comment: `_sign_vals` doesn't return anything. You need to add a `return` to it like this: `return this.computehmac( /* ... */ ).then( /* ... */ )`

Comment: Thanks. I wanna return "this.output" though which is formatted version of computehmac result